# How to change an Gif ImageView multiple times using the same button Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to make something that's probably easy to do but I couldn't find any ways to do it. Basically, when I click on a button I want it to change one Imageview with the second Imageview, but then again, when I click on the same button, I want that second Imageview to be changed to the third Imageview, is that possible? So far, I've only done the first part, I can only change one Imageview with another, but can't do it to the third one. Here's my code

```
changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GifImageView gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.greengif);
            gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the click event.

```
int count = 0;
changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GifImageView gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.greengif);
        if (count == 0) {
            // show the second image
            gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        } else if (count == 1) {
            // show the third image
            gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```